# Apply bootstrap grid to a part of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

I want to make a sidebar with a **fixed** width, and use bootstrap grid to the rest of the page. The following code ([JSBin](https://jsbin.com/bipigoqaju/2/edit?html,output)) does not work: we see that the bootstrap grid is applied to the entire page.

Does anyone know if it is achievable?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .fixed {
        width: 202px;
      }
      .sidebar {
        display: none;
      }
      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .sidebar {
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          left: 0;
          z-index: 1000;
          display: block;
          background-color: #f5f5f5;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="fixed sidebar">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
          abcsfdsqdfdqfdqsdfdqfdsqdfssd
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
          efg
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use Waffle Grid for the grid system instead of Boostrap's grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed and absolute positioned elements are no longer part of the document flow, so they don't reserve the space they normally would. In your example, that means the sidebar doesn't push the rest of the content over, which is why you see it overlap the main content.

What I find normally works is to use the fluid container (so the page content spans the whole viewport) and then add padding to the "main" section to clear the horizontal space the sidebar would otherwise overlap.

Here's an example based off of a project I've built recently:

#### CSS

```
/* Hide for mobile, show later */
.sidebar
{
    display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px)
{
    .sidebar
    {
        position: fixed;
        top: 55px;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1000;
        display: block;
        padding: 0;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
        width: 175px;
    }

        .sidebar.student
        {
            background-color: #71B1D1;
            color: #fff;
            border-right: 1px solid #eee;
        }
}

/*
 * Main content
 */

.main
{
    padding: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px)
{
    .main
    {
        padding-left: 215px;
        padding-right: 40px;
    }
}
```

#### Markup

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Export</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li><a href="">Nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
        <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="">More navigation</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
        <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="main">

        <h2>Content Header</h2>

        <p>Some content here...</p>

        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>
                &copy; 2017
            </p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://jsbin.com/giwozanavi

Code: https://jsbin.com/giwozanavi/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Thank you... `padding-left` inside `container-fluid` is indeed a clean solution. But I am trying to add a background color to **the full part on the right**. `<div class="main" style="background-color:red; position:fixed; top: 0px; bottom:0">` used to work in one of my examples with dynamic-width sidebar, but it does not work here. Do you have a clean solution to add such a background color?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend used fixed positioning on both sections. Regardless, with my example, the easiest solution is to apply a background to the body element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .fixed {
            width: 202px;
        }

        .sidebar {
            display: none;
        }        
        @media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1124px) {
            .fixed {
                width: 140px;
            }
        }
        @media (min-width: 768px) {
                .sidebar {
                    position: fixed;
                    top: 0;
                    bottom: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    z-index: 1000;
                    display: block;
                    background-color: #f5f5f5;
                }
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="fixed sidebar">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        abcsfdsqdfdqfdqsdfdqfdsqdfssd
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        efg
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think it works perfectly; here is a [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/miruwopifu/1/edit?html,output).

Comment: You will see the problem when you change the width of the page: the width of the sidebar is not fixed; there is a jump... and why `140px`?

Comment: i think , if you set position:fixed
you must change with of sidebar dynamically ,
when page with is between 481 px and 1124 px , i set sidebar to 140 px
, to avoid getting behind another div

Comment: That example does not use fixed-width sidebar.

Comment: Depends on your definition of fixed width - it uses the column classes, so it's always a fixed percentage of the viewport.